# Heatmap of correlation matrix using seaborn not displaying properly at the top and bottom row

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

I ran the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
sns.heatmap(df_corr.drop(['Revenue'], axis = 1).corr(), cmap="RdYlGn")
plt.suptitle("Pearson Correlation Heatmap")
plt.show()
```

to produce the correlation heatmap below:
[image: corrheatmap]

But if you look at the top and bottom rows, you can see only half a box is displayed at the top and bottom rows. How do I get it to display the full box at the top and bottom rows? I have tried to change figsize but it didn't work.

Many thanks.

Comment: known bug: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773

Comment: What is your matplotlib version?

Comment: It’s 3.1.1, so it’s time for an upgrade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading matplotlib to the last version (3.1.3) should solve the issue.

- using anaconda: `conda update matplotlib`
- using pip: `pip install -U matplotlib`